# Application of the datepicker on css class to multiple input elements but it fails

Tags: datepicker

I want to apply jQuery ui datepicker on a multiple elements of css custom class but it only working with the first element and fails with the rest of elements please suggest the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$(".myClass").datepicker()
```

even this is failing?

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){
   $(this).datepicker();
}
```

Comment: i tried the above solution prior asking the quetion that too doesn't works